# Numpy load txt strange behavior

Tags: python, csv, numpy

I have a csv file, comma separated that I want to import into a numpy array, just selecting several cols each time. My file has 44 columns. It works perfect if I try to load any column before the 16.

```
data=np.loadtxt(open(file,"rU"),delimiter=",",usecols=(7,8,10,15))
```

However, if try to load a column beyond the 16th:

```
data=np.loadtxt(open(file,"rb"),delimiter=",",usecols=(16,17))
```

It returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 839, in loadtxt
vals = [vals[i] for i in usecols]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

The file seems OK, since it was generated by a python script that write each line of the csv.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you include a few of the rows from the csv?

Comment: What happens when you take one row of the file and do a len(row) on it? Are you certain that you do not have any truncated rows? What would happen if you used csv.DictReader or csv.reader to bring in the file and examine the columns?

Comment: Your first open has 'rU' while your second is 'rb' check that they are the same in your test.

Comment: Thanks! It worked in another computer, so I guess that I have to revise my python installation and related packages. The difference between 'rb' and 'rU' does not seem to affect the output, I tried both of them to get sure that the error was not related with the access to the file. I actually can recover the content using a csv reader, so I guess that the problem is maybe in the numpy installation.